# TensorFlow Neural Network LSTM: Loss Function for Temporal Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, loss-function

Let's say we are trying to predict future earthquakes based on previous earthquakes. A visualisation of part of a dataset containing sequences of earthquakes may look like this (features to the left, labels to the right, x=month, y=earthquake magnitude):
[image: features - labels]
You and I can see that the pattern here is that when there are two magnitude 5 earthquakes in succession, they are followed by a magnitude 8 earthquake then a magnitude 4 earthquake. Those earthquakes may appear with a variation of 3-5 months away, but the magnitudes are the same when they do.

Training an LSTM on this data with a mean squared error loss function produces the following predictions (the dashed line):
[image: predictions]
It's done exactly as we've asked it, it's learned to predict the mean per timestep. However, this is a poor prediction in terms of what the model is intended to do.

For you or I looking at the data, we could surmise that the first predicted earthquake is a magnitude 8, and taking into account the variance in timestep our best prediction would be that it happens at timestep 8. We'd essentially be doing a mean error in the temporal axis, as well as the value axis.

**What loss function can be used to do this in TensorFlow?**

I've been searching but only finding material relating to per timestep error.
I started trying a few methods that I thought might give better results like `tf.sort` on the labels and predictions before performing mean squared error, and then also `tf.argsort` on the labels and predictions and doing mean squared error on them to give a temporal error, but argsort has no gradients for back-propagation so started trying to write custom gradients, which just feels like overkill when a solution must already exist? (p.s. I'm comfortable with TensorFlow but I'm no expert).

If someone can point me in the right direction I'd be hugely appreciative!

Here's the code that demonstrates the example above:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

features = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0], 
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0], 
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0]]).reshape(6, 7, 1).astype(np.float32)
labels = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                   [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0],
                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                   [0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0]]).reshape(6, 7, 1).astype(np.float32)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 2))
plt.plot(np.concatenate((features[:, :, 0].T, labels[:, :, 0].T)) * 10)
plt.axvline(features.shape[1]-1)
plt.title('<- Features vs. Labels ->')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.show()

def train_input_fn(features, labels):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
    return dataset.shuffle(len(features)).repeat().batch(len(features))
def predict_input_fn(features):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(features)
    return dataset.batch(len(features))

def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    lstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(7, 1)))(features)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='linear')(lstm)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=outputs)

    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, outputs)
    optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
    train_op = optimiser.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn)
estimator.train(input_fn=lambda:train_input_fn(features, labels), steps=100)
predictions = np.array(list(estimator.predict(input_fn=lambda:predict_input_fn(features))))

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 2))
plt.plot(np.concatenate((features[:, :, 0].T, labels[:, :, 0].T)) * 10)
plt.plot(np.concatenate((features[:, :, 0].T, predictions[:, :, 0].T)) * 10, ls='--')
plt.axvline(features.shape[1]-1)
plt.title('<- Features vs. Labels -> (with model predictions \'--\')')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.show()
```